# Suppose there are 2 classes A and B, is it possible to create an object of A in B and of B in A?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
Class A
{
B b1=new B();
}
Class B
{
A a1=new A();
}
```

I'm talking about something like this? Is it possible?

Comment: This seems like something that you could very easily try yourself.

Comment: I'm working on a project which requires something of this sort but I wasn't able to run the program so I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: Since Eclipse is just an IDE, it might be useful also to mention which language you are talking about...

Comment: java is the language

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. The following *compiles* just fine:

```
class A {
    B b1 = new B();
    public A() {
        System.out.println("A constructor");
    }
}
class B {
    A a1 = new A();
    public B() {
        System.out.println("B constructor");
    }
}

public class HelloWorld {
     public static void main(String []args) {
         A a0 = new A();
         System.out.println("Done");
     }
}
```

However, as shown in the output, it's generally a bad idea:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at B.<init>(HelloWorld.java:8)
    at A.<init>(HelloWorld.java:3)
    at B.<init>(HelloWorld.java:8)
    at A.<init>(HelloWorld.java:3)
    at B.<init>(HelloWorld.java:8)
    :
    at A.<init>(HelloWorld.java:3)
    at B.<init>(HelloWorld.java:8)
    at A.<init>(HelloWorld.java:3)
    at B.<init>(HelloWorld.java:8)
```

The fact that construction of an `A` tries to create a `B`, and construction of a `B` tries to create an `A`, means that you'll get caught in infinite regress, eventually running out of stack space.

You *can* safely have two objects refer to each other but it's generally done *after* the construction phase, something like:

```
class A {
    B b;
    public A() {
        System.out.println("A constructor");
    }
    public void setOther(B bx) {
        System.out.println("A linker");
        b = bx;
    }
}
class B {
    A a;
    public B() {
        System.out.println("B constructor");
    }
    public void setOther(A ax) {
        System.out.println("B linker");
        a = ax;
    }
}
public class HelloWorld{
     public static void main(String []args){
         A a0 = new A();
         B b0 = new B();
         a0.setOther(b0);
         b0.setOther(a0);
         System.out.println("Done");
     }
}
```

The output of that shows:

```
A constructor
B constructor
A linker
B linker
Done
```

Comment: That's exactly the error i'm getting. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: The "workaround" is to figure out what you want to accomplish.  You definitely don't want to have a class whose constructor causes an infinite number of objects to be created.  But what _do_ you want?

Comment: Each of the class has methods which are to be used by the other class hence I require creating an object of the other class.

Comment: In this case the scenario is the most important thing. You may also use some pattern but it depends from the case you need to reproduce

Comment: Thank you i'm able to create the objects.